# @page rule not woking in browsers

Tags: html, css, pdf, documentation

Why is the @page rule not working in browsers? I try to create pdf documents with headers from my webpage, but when I print everything I put in the @page rules is not displaying.

Comment: That only works on odd days, not even days such as today. Seriously, your question is not even 2 lines long and it doesn't include any useful details such as a minimal example showing what is not working. Please elaborate your question, add details, add code samples showing what happens. Then maybe someone could help you.

Comment: My comment was a lot more helpful than both your question and your comment. I helpfully suggested that your question - as it stands now - cannot be answered, even by an expert of Print Media CSS. I wouldn't call myself an expert on that by the way, but I've worked with PDF since 1997 and with a tool that converts HTML to PDF (using amongst other things page rules) for the last five years. So I _could_ actually be qualified to answer your question, _if_ you would go through the trouble to supply enough details (as stated in the rules for asking questions by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question verbosity (or lack of) I would suggest you to use some external service/solution that someone already did and understand better.

I personally use html2pdf (https://html2pdf.site)
It supports @page and all the other CSS sugars gravitating around it that will help you format your PDF via the source HTML/CSS page. I would say it does surprisingly good job (and fast).

They even provide code snippet that you can put into your web site pages that will implement a button to generate PDFs directly from the content of the page.

Good luck.

Comment: So this is an external service not part of the browser itself or its print function. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Well... It can't be more simple. Just add these snippets (provided within their templates) in your HTML. Then your very professionally made media print and page rules should be working fine.

**IN YOUR CSS**

```
.pdfButton { /* some style for your button */}
```

**IN YOUR HTML**

```
<!-- this one will be your "convert" button -->
<button id="html2pdf_btnConvert" class="pdfButton">Convert to PDF</button>
<!-- this one will be your "download" button once the conversion is complete -->
<a href="#" id="html2pdf_btnDownload" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
```

Note: regarding the documentation of HTML2PDF *the "convert" element ID must ALWAYS be* "**html2pdf_btnConvert**" and *the "download" element ID must ALWAYS be* "**html2pdf_btnDownload**", the element itself can be anything (button, img, div, etc.).

**IN YOUR JAVASCRIPT**

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(), $("#html2pdf_btnDownload").hide(), $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").on("click", function() {
    let t = window.location.href;
    $("#html2pdf_btnDownload").hide(), $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").prop("disabled", !0);
    let e = $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").text();
    $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").text("Converting..."), $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        json: !0,
        url: "https://html2pdf.site/proxy.php",
        crossDomain: !0,
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {
            url: "http://thespineapple-api.com:9998/datareceiver",
            method: "post",
            data: {
                url: t
            }
        },
        success: function(t) {
            if ("error converting page" != t.url) {
                var o = t.url.replace("http://", "https://");
                $("#html2pdf_btnDownload").attr("href", o), $("#html2pdf_btnDownload").show()
                $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").attr("href", o), $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").hide()
            } else alert("This page is not suitable for our conversion system.");
            $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").text(e), $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").prop("disabled", !1)
        },
        error: function() {
            $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").text(e), $("#html2pdf_btnConvert").prop("disabled", !1), $("#html2pdf_btnDownload").attr("href", "#"), $("#html2pdf_btnDownload").hide()
        }
    })
});

</script>
```

This should work.